# Need advice on how to record video and audio using my RasPi

Tags: raspbian, audio, camera, video

As an experiment and learning project, I want to create an action camera using my Raspberry Pi Zero W, the latest version of the RasPi camera module and an i2S microphone.

I have found some RasPi action cam examples online. There seems to be several good tutorials on how to the RasPi camera module. And a few tutorials regarding i2S mics and audio.

However, I'm struggling to find good resources on how to record/encode video together with audio using the RasPi camera module and an i2S microphone.

The goal of my project is to use my RasPi Zero W as an action cam, and download all my recorded videos from the RasPi SD card to my iMac via a USB connection.

Can anyone offer any advice on how I can do this? Do you know of any good tutorials, APIs or examples?

One idea I had was using FFMPEG to open the camera source and the i2S microphone source to stream the recording to an H.264/MPEG-4 file? Would that be possible?

I do have a larger learning project in mind, but I need to start here first.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a very similar project and I hope this helps you. Pure Python (besides the audio/video muxing part).

https://github.com/kpolley/Python_AVrecorder

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will check it out. I will report back if I have success with it.